# Android ListView Adapter performance

Tags: android, performance, listview, adapter

In my application I have a ListActivity. In this Activity I need to display list of actions (for example, Action1, Action2, Action3, Action4). In intent calling this listActivity, I pass boolean value (flag). If flag is true, I need to display all actions. Else I need to display only Action1 and Action2.
I see 2 ways to do it:
1) create two string-arrays (call it actions_1 and actions_2)  in resources file, and override onStart() method for my ListActivity like this:

```
String[] action_list;
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();    
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    boolean flag = intent.getBooleanExtra("isPayable", false);
    if (flag)
        action_list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.actions_1);
    else
        action_list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.actions_2);
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, action_list);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

2) create custom Adapter for my ListView, and in getView() method hide items setting layout_height=0dp.
What way is better for performance? Maybe, there is another, better way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will ever notice the "performance improvement" in a normal App unless you show a list of thousands of items (and as you say you will only have 4?). In any case, I would use option 1), since you check your flag only once, compared with "N" if you put your logic inside a custom adapter that needs to check items that will never be shown.